# How do I solve this blank screen issue of my kotlin app?

Tags: android, kotlin

So, when I compile the code for my splash screen and run it, it only shows a blank screen. The layout editor perfectly renders the screen. I recently switched to Kotlin, so maybe I did some mistake in the code.

```
package com.superstar.scrolls2

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class LauncherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.launcher_layout)
        Handler().postDelayed({
            var i : Intent=Intent(this@LauncherActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }, 5000)
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.superstar.scrolls2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Scrolls2" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
        <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/parchment_chinese"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/scroll_one_coloured"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="124dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="163dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/medievalsharp"
        android:text="Scrolls"
        android:textColor="#9A5712"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="59dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="157dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, the splash screen is completely black with the toolbar at the top showing the app name. Just to test, I wrote the same screen with java which works all good. The app doesn't crash or anything. And just for testing purposes, I didn't finish() launcher activity to know if it actually starts the LoginActivity, but it doesn't since there's only one activity in the stack.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are overriding the wrong `onCreate()`,it will never be called and you content won't be set
use

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

instead of

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?)
```

Comment: OH YEAH you are right damn it. Thank you very much. I thought that was the onCreate for kotlin sigh -_-

Comment: `I thought that was the onCreate for kotlin sigh` overrides don't change because you're using a different language

Comment: Glad I could help, please accept the answer if you think it answered your question.